# Eloquent Model adding row without "created_at" and "updated_at" fields

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, eloquent

So in my SQL I have table that contains only three fields -- row id, person id and status id, and I want to add new rows using Laravel models, and when I use

```
$a = new AssignedStatus;
$a->person_id = $person_id;
$a->status_id = $status_id;
$a->save();
```

I get SQL error telling that columns "created_at" and "updated_at" are not found in this table. Is it somehow possible to get rid of them and just insert row, or is it easier to use `DB::table` connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In AssignedStatus model you need to declare:

```
public $timestamps = false
```